# compress citation of multiple set members in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I must admit that I feel a bit stupid at the moment. I am pretty shure that I have seen this on sx already but I don't find it any more since it has been hidden in a comment as far as I remember.

Citing members of a `@Set` in `biblatex` with `Biber` I would like to compress citations similar to normal full entries - see image and MWE below. Going through the `biblatex` documentation I did not find this point...

Here is what it should look like:

[image]

Any input anyone?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,mcite,subentry,sorting=nty,sortsets=true,backref=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat{entrysetcount}{\mknumalph{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Beiglboeck:Koffein,
  author    = {Beiglböck, Wolfgang},
  title     = {Koffein},
  year      = {2016},
  date      = {2016-07-01},
  publisher = {Springer},
  location  = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
  isbn      = {978-3-662-49564-3},
  url       = {https://www.ebook.de/de/product/26446638/wolfgang_beiglboeck_koffein.html},
  ean       = {9783662495643},
}
@Book{fish:drugs,
  mainsubtitle = {Drugs and Society},
  year         = {2006},
  editor       = {Jefferson M. Fish},
  maintitle    = {U.S.~public policy},
  publisher    = {Rowman \& Littlefield Publishers, Inc},
  location     = {Lanham, Maryland},
  isbn         = {0-7425-4245-9},
  sortname     = {Jefferson M. Fish},
  sorttitle    = {U.S. public policy Drugs and Society},
  options      = {dataonly},
}
@Set{set:fish:drugs,
  entryset     = {fish:drugs:gable:alt,fish:drugs:cleveland:use,fish:drugs:evans:intro},
  options      = {multivolumehead=fish:drugs},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:evans:intro,
  crossref   = {fish:drugs},
  author     = {Richard M. Evans and Stanley Neustadter},
  chapter    = {6},
  title      = {Legalization: An Introduction},
  pages      = {129-148},
  sorttitle  = {06 Legalization: An Introduction},
  options    = {dataonly},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:cleveland:use,
  crossref   = {fish:drugs},
  author     = {Mary M. Cleveland},
  chapter    = {9a},
  title      = {Use, 'Abuse', Adverse Health Effects, and Addiction},
  pages      = {197-200},
  sorttitle  = {09 Use, Abuse, Adverse Health Effects, and Addiction},
  options    = {dataonly},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:gable:alt,
  crossref   = {fish:drugs},
  author     = {Robert S. Gable},
  chapter    = {7},
  title      = {Acute Toxicity of Drugs versus Regulatory Status},
  pages      = {149-161},
  sorttitle  = {07 Acute Toxicity of Drugs versus Regulatory Status},
}
@Book{A,
  author      = {René Goscinny and Albert Uderzo},
  maintitle   = {Asterix und Obelix},
  year        = {1959--2018},
  publisher   = {Dargaud},
  location    = {Paris},
  volumes     = {99},
  options     = {dataonly},
}
@Set{set:A,
  entryset    = {A:V1,A:V2,A:V3,A:V4,A:V5,A:V6},
  options     = {multivolumehead=A},
}
@Book{A:V1,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Asterix der Gallier},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 01},
  year        = {1959},
  isbn        = {1234567890123},
  volume      = {1},
}
@Book{A:V2,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Asterix und Kleopatra},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 02},
  year        = {1968},
  isbn        = {2345678901234},
  volume      = {2},
}
@Book{A:V3,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Asterix als Gladiator},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 03},
  year        = {1969},
  isbn        = {3456789012345},
  volume      = {3},
}
@Book{A:V4,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Der Kampf der Häuptlinge},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 04},
  year        = {1969},
  isbn        = {4567890123456},
  volume      = {4},
}
@Book{A:V5,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Die goldene Sichel},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 05},
  year        = {1970},
  isbn        = {5678901234567},
  volume      = {5},
}
@Book{A:V6,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Tour de France},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 06},
  year        = {1970},
  isbn        = {6789012345678},
  volume      = {6},
}
@Book{DHS:base,
  editor    = {{Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen e.~V.}},
  sortname  = {{Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen}},
  year      = {2017},
  url       = {www.dhs.de},
  urldate   = {2018-04-30},
  maintitle = {Suchtmedizinische Reihe},
  options   = {dataonly},
}
@Book{DHS:nik,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  title     = {Tabakabhängigkeit},
  sorttitle = {Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen Suchtmedizinische Reihe 01},
  volume    = {1},
  isbn      = {978-3-937587-00-4},
}
@Book{DHS:alk,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  title     = {Alkoholabhängigkeit},
  sorttitle = {Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen Suchtmedizinische Reihe 02},
  volume    = {2},
  isbn      = {978-3-937587-01-1},
}
@Book{DHS:drogen,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  title     = {Drogenabhängigkeit},
  sorttitle = {Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen Suchtmedizinische Reihe 04},
  volume    = {4},
  isbn      = {978-3-937587-03-5},
}
@Set{DHS:SMR,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  entryset  = {DHS:alk,DHS:nik,DHS:drogen},
  options   = {multivolumehead=DHS:base},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}\parindent=0pt\relax\parskip=2ex\relax
\nocite{*}

Cleveland\supercite{fish:drugs:cleveland:use} writes some hard stuff.

Be adviced that after heavy stuff like this\msupercite{Beiglboeck:Koffein,DHS:SMR,set:fish:drugs} you should relax\supercite{A:V2,A:V3,A:V4,A:V6} a bit, were the last citation should look like the hard coded variants\textsuperscript{4b-d,f} or.\textsuperscript{4b-d,4f}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416444/35864 help?

Comment: @moewe Like always you're my hero - that was the question I did not find anymore. Perfect. And it works. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? thx and big hugs...

Comment: BTW: There may be some rough edges with that solution. There must be a reason why I abandoned including this in `biblatex-ext` ... or maybe it was just that the code is so complicated. If you find an issue with the code, just ask a new question.

Comment: @moewe yep - that's perfectly ok since it in fact **is** a duplicate....

Comment: @moewe I'll have to check and understand the solution provided and I'll keep an eye on side effects and possible issues...

Comment: Interestingly there seems to be a difference between the definition of a `@set` in the bibfile and via `\defbibentryset`. While the second does work for the combination of members of different sets the first does not. The previous set block has to be terminated via `\ifdef{\cbx@lastnumber}{\iffieldequals{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}{}{\usebibmacro{cite:dump}\ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntb}}{-1}{\multicitedelim\usebibmacro{cite:init}}{}}}{}%` as the very first command in `\renewbibmacro*{cite:comp:inset}` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416444/35864.

Comment: A very similar check is already present (maybe it is faulty, I didn't check the entire logic). Can you ask a new question with an example that reproduces the undesirable behaviour, so I can have a closer look, please? (Of course you can immediately answer with your solution and accept that later, but I would like to see exactly what goes wrong in my code and fix it.) If you don't want to write a question, send me the example via mail, you can find my address in the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf).