# compress citation of set members in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

Using the excellent solution to compress citations for `@set` members provided by moewe in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416444/35864) results in an unexpected behaviour of the compression mechanism if members of different sets are combined in one `\cite` command. Obviously the internal change of the `@set` is not reliable recognized so the macro gets confused.

In the following MWE I have implemented a check for the change of sets that can be switched on or off by `\toggletrue{adapted}` resp. `\togglefalse{adapted}` to reproduce both variations.

What I just don't get is why moewes solution does not work as expected - so basically it's more a question out of curiosity...

The result of the MWE is

[image]

where in line 3 the original code is used and in line 4 the adapted one.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,mcite,subentry,sorting=nty,sortsets=true,backref=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{fish:drugs,
  mainsubtitle = {Drugs and Society},
  year = {2006},
  editor   = {Jefferson M. Fish},
  maintitle= {U.S.~public policy},
  publisher= {Rowman \& Littlefield Publishers, Inc},
  location = {Lanham, Maryland},
  isbn = {0-7425-4245-9},
  sortname = {Jefferson M. Fish},
  sorttitle= {U.S. public policy Drugs and Society},
  options  = {dataonly},
}
@Set{set:fish:drugs,
  entryset = {fish:drugs:gable:alt,fish:drugs:cleveland:use,fish:drugs:evans:intro},
  options  = {multivolumehead=fish:drugs},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:evans:intro,
  crossref   = {fish:drugs},
  author = {Richard M. Evans and Stanley Neustadter},
  chapter= {6},
  title  = {Legalization: An Introduction},
  pages  = {129-148},
  sorttitle  = {06 Legalization: An Introduction},
  options= {dataonly},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:cleveland:use,
  crossref   = {fish:drugs},
  author = {Mary M. Cleveland},
  chapter= {9a},
  title  = {Use, 'Abuse', Adverse Health Effects, and Addiction},
  pages  = {197-200},
  sorttitle  = {09 Use, Abuse, Adverse Health Effects, and Addiction},
  options= {dataonly},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:gable:alt,
  crossref   = {fish:drugs},
  author = {Robert S. Gable},
  chapter= {7},
  title  = {Acute Toxicity of Drugs versus Regulatory Status},
  pages  = {149-161},
  sorttitle  = {07 Acute Toxicity of Drugs versus Regulatory Status},
}
@Book{A,
  author  = {René Goscinny and Albert Uderzo},
  maintitle   = {Asterix und Obelix},
  year    = {1959--2018},
  publisher   = {Dargaud},
  location= {Paris},
  volumes = {99},
  options = {dataonly},
}
@Set{set:A,
  entryset= {A:V1,A:V2,A:V3,A:V4,A:V5,A:V6},
  options = {multivolumehead=A},
}
@Book{A:V1,
  crossref= {A},
  title   = {Asterix der Gallier},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 01},
  year    = {1959},
  isbn    = {1234567890123},
  volume  = {1},
}
@Book{A:V2,
  crossref= {A},
  title   = {Asterix und Kleopatra},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 02},
  year    = {1968},
  isbn    = {2345678901234},
  volume  = {2},
}
@Book{A:V3,
  crossref= {A},
  title   = {Asterix als Gladiator},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 03},
  year    = {1969},
  isbn    = {3456789012345},
  volume  = {3},
}
@Book{A:V4,
  crossref= {A},
  title   = {Der Kampf der Häuptlinge},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 04},
  year    = {1969},
  isbn    = {4567890123456},
  volume  = {4},
}
@Book{A:V5,
  crossref= {A},
  title   = {Die goldene Sichel},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 05},
  year    = {1970},
  isbn    = {5678901234567},
  volume  = {5},
}
@Book{A:V6,
  crossref= {A},
  title   = {Tour de France},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 06},
  year    = {1970},
  isbn    = {6789012345678},
  volume  = {6},
}
@Book{DHS:base,
  editor= {{Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen e.~V.}},
  sortname  = {{Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen}},
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {www.dhs.de},
  urldate   = {2018-04-30},
  maintitle = {Suchtmedizinische Reihe},
  options   = {dataonly},
}
@Book{DHS:nik,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  title = {Tabakabhängigkeit},
  sorttitle = {Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen Suchtmedizinische Reihe 01},
  volume= {1},
  isbn  = {978-3-937587-00-4},
}
@Book{DHS:alk,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  title = {Alkoholabhängigkeit},
  sorttitle = {Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen Suchtmedizinische Reihe 02},
  volume= {2},
  isbn  = {978-3-937587-01-1},
}
@Book{DHS:drogen,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  title = {Drogenabhängigkeit},
  sorttitle = {Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen Suchtmedizinische Reihe 04},
  volume= {4},
  isbn  = {978-3-937587-03-5},
}
@Set{DHS:SMR,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  entryset  = {DHS:alk,DHS:nik,DHS:drogen},
  options   = {multivolumehead=DHS:base},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\newtoggle{adapted}\togglefalse{adapted}

\makeatletter
% compress set member citations
% code by moewe
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416444/biber-and-biblatex-reference-to-multiple-subentries
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470391/compress-citation-of-multiple-set-members-in-biblatex
\newcounter{cbx@tempcntc}
\newcounter{cbx@tempcntd}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:init}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastnumber
  \global\undef\cbx@lastprefix
  \global\undef\cbx@lastcount
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcnta}{0}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntb}{-2}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntc}{0}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntd}{-1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:comp:inset}{%
  \iftoggle{adapted}% new
    {\ifdef{\cbx@lastnumber}
       {\iffieldequals{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}
          {}% same label number
          {%  label number changed
           \usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
           \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntb}}{-1}
          {\multicitedelim%
            \usebibmacro{cite:init}}% cite reset
          {}}}%%%<- terminate previous entry
       {}}
     {}% end new
    \stepcounter{cbx@tempcntd}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    (( test {\iffieldundef{labelprefix}} and test {\ifundef\cbx@lastprefix} )
       or
       test {\iffieldequals{labelprefix}{\cbx@lastprefix}})
   and test {\iffieldequals{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}}
    }
    {}
    {\setcounter{cbx@tempcntc}{0}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
     \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntb}}{-1}
       {\multicitedelim}
       {}}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      (( test {\iffieldundef{labelprefix}} and test {\ifundef\cbx@lastprefix} )
         or
         test {\iffieldequals{labelprefix}{\cbx@lastprefix}})
     and test {\iffieldequals{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}}
      }
    {}
    {\printfield{labelnumber}%
     \savefield{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}}%
        \ifnumequal{\thefield{entrysetcount}}{\value{cbx@tempcntd}}
      {\savefield{entrykey}{\cbx@lastkey}%
       \savefield{entrysetcount}{\cbx@lastcount}%
       \stepcounter{cbx@tempcntc}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntd}}{0}
         {\multicitedelim}
         {}%
       \printfield{entrysetcount}}}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntd}{\thefield{entrysetcount}}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntb}{-1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:dump}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntc}}{0}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntc}}{1}
       {\bibrangedash}
       {\multicitedelim}%
     \bibhyperref[\cbx@lastkey]{%
     \printtext[entrysetcount]{\cbx@lastcount}}}
    {}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntc}{0}%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcnta}}{0}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcnta}}{1}
       {\bibrangedash}
       {\multicitedelim}%
     \bibhyperref[\cbx@lastkey]{%
       \ifdef\cbx@lastprefix
         {\printtext[labelprefix]{\cbx@lastprefix}}
         {}%
       \printtext[labelnumber]{\cbx@lastnumber}}}
    {}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcnta}{0}%
  \global\undef\cbx@lastprefix}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}\parindent=0pt\relax\parskip=2ex\relax
\nocite{*}

%Cleveland\supercite{fish:drugs:cleveland:use} writes some hard stuff.
Asterix loves fish.\supercite{fish:drugs:evans:intro,fish:drugs:gable:alt,fish:drugs:cleveland:use}

Obelix loves drugs.\supercite{DHS:nik,DHS:alk,DHS:drogen}

Idefix loves Asterix, rotten fish and drugs.\supercite{DHS:nik,DHS:alk,DHS:drogen,A:V1,A:V3,A:V4,A:V5,fish:drugs:evans:intro,fish:drugs:gable:alt,fish:drugs:cleveland:use}

\toggletrue{adapted}

Years ago Idefix loved Asterix, no drugs and good fish.\supercite{DHS:nik,DHS:alk,DHS:drogen,A:V1,A:V3,A:V4,A:V5,fish:drugs:evans:intro,fish:drugs:gable:alt,fish:drugs:cleveland:use} These times have been better\dots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for spotting this. There was a bug in my answer to [Biber and Biblatex: reference to multiple subentries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416444/35864). Essentially the issue was that an auxiliary counter was not reset when the labels (`labelprefix`+`labelnumber`) were dumped/printed. Since that counter is used to check whether or not to print `\multicitedelim`, we could get a spurious `\multicitedelim` in some situations.

The following code should fix that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, mcite, subentry, sortsets=true]{biblatex}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% the first two counters are already defined in numeric-comp.cbx
% cbx@tempcnta % no. of labelnumbers we skipped
% cbx@tempcntb % 'predicted' labelnumber for current cite
\newcounter{cbx@tempcntc}% no. of entrysetcounts we skipped
\newcounter{cbx@tempcntd}% 'predicted' entrysetcount
\renewbibmacro*{cite:init}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastnumber
  \global\undef\cbx@lastprefix
  \global\undef\cbx@lastcount
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcnta}{0}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntb}{-2}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntc}{0}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntd}{-1}}

\newcommand*{\cbx@iflabelnumberequalslast}{%
  \iffieldequals{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}}

% \iffieldequals is false even if both are empty/undef
% so we need a special test for that case
% this test is optimised for performance and laziness
% rather than prettiness, not that it would matter a lot...
\newcommand*{\cbx@iflabelprefixequalslast}{%
  \ifundef\cbx@lastprefix
    {\iffieldundef{labelprefix}
       {\@firstoftwo}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\iffieldequals{labelprefix}{\cbx@lastprefix}
       {\@firstoftwo}
       {\@secondoftwo}}}

% \cbx@iflabelnumberequalslast and \cbx@iflabelprefixequalslast
\newcommand*{\cbx@iflabelequalslast}{%
  \iffieldequals{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}
    {\cbx@iflabelprefixequalslast
       {\@firstoftwo}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:comp:inset}{%
  \stepcounter{cbx@tempcntd}%
  % the calls for false \cbx@iflabelequalslast
  % are split between stuff that happens before
  % the link and that happens within the link
  \cbx@iflabelequalslast
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
     \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntb}}{-1}
       {\multicitedelim}
       {}}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \cbx@iflabelequalslast
      {}
      {\setcounter{cbx@tempcntd}{-1}%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelnumber}%
       \savefield{labelprefix}{\cbx@lastprefix}%
       \savefield{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}}%
    \ifnumequal{\thefield{entrysetcount}}{\value{cbx@tempcntd}}
      {\savefield{entrykey}{\cbx@lastkey}%
       \savefield{entrysetcount}{\cbx@lastcount}%
       \stepcounter{cbx@tempcntc}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntd}}{0}
         {\multicitedelim}
         {}%
       \printfield{entrysetcount}}}%
    \setcounter{cbx@tempcntd}{\thefield{entrysetcount}}%
    \setcounter{cbx@tempcntb}{-1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:dump}{%
  % dump subentry
  \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntc}}{0}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntc}}{1}
       {\bibrangedash}
       {\multicitedelim}%
     \bibhyperref[\cbx@lastkey]{%
       \printtext[entrysetcount]{\cbx@lastcount}}}
    {}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntc}{0}%
  % dump labelnumber (+labelprefix)
  \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcnta}}{0}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcnta}}{1}
       {\bibrangedash}
       {\multicitedelim}%
     \bibhyperref[\cbx@lastkey]{%
       \ifdef\cbx@lastprefix
         {\printtext[labelprefix]{\cbx@lastprefix}}
         {}%
       \printtext[labelnumber]{\cbx@lastnumber}}%
     \global\undef\cbx@lastprefix}
    {}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcnta}{0}}
\makeatother


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{fish:drugs,
  mainsubtitle = {Drugs and Society},
  year = {2006},
  editor   = {Jefferson M. Fish},
  maintitle= {U.S.~public policy},
  publisher= {Rowman \& Littlefield Publishers, Inc},
  location = {Lanham, Maryland},
  isbn = {0-7425-4245-9},
  sortname = {Jefferson M. Fish},
  sorttitle= {U.S. public policy Drugs and Society},
  options  = {dataonly},
}
@Set{set:fish:drugs,
  entryset = {fish:drugs:gable:alt,fish:drugs:cleveland:use,fish:drugs:evans:intro},
  options  = {multivolumehead=fish:drugs},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:evans:intro,
  crossref   = {fish:drugs},
  author = {Richard M. Evans and Stanley Neustadter},
  chapter= {6},
  title  = {Legalization: An Introduction},
  pages  = {129-148},
  sorttitle  = {06 Legalization: An Introduction},
  options= {dataonly},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:cleveland:use,
  crossref   = {fish:drugs},
  author = {Mary M. Cleveland},
  chapter= {9a},
  title  = {Use, 'Abuse', Adverse Health Effects, and Addiction},
  pages  = {197-200},
  sorttitle  = {09 Use, Abuse, Adverse Health Effects, and Addiction},
  options= {dataonly},
}
@Inbook{fish:drugs:gable:alt,
  crossref   = {fish:drugs},
  author = {Robert S. Gable},
  chapter= {7},
  title  = {Acute Toxicity of Drugs versus Regulatory Status},
  pages  = {149-161},
  sorttitle  = {07 Acute Toxicity of Drugs versus Regulatory Status},
}
@Book{A,
  author  = {René Goscinny and Albert Uderzo},
  maintitle   = {Asterix und Obelix},
  year    = {1959--2018},
  publisher   = {Dargaud},
  location= {Paris},
  volumes = {99},
  options = {dataonly},
}
@Set{set:A,
  entryset= {A:V1,A:V2,A:V3,A:V4,A:V5,A:V6},
  options = {multivolumehead=A},
}
@Book{A:V1,
  crossref= {A},
  title   = {Asterix der Gallier},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 01},
  year    = {1959},
  isbn    = {1234567890123},
  volume  = {1},
}
@Book{A:V2,
  crossref= {A},
  title   = {Asterix und Kleopatra},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 02},
  year    = {1968},
  isbn    = {2345678901234},
  volume  = {2},
}
@Book{A:V3,
  crossref= {A},
  title   = {Asterix als Gladiator},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 03},
  year    = {1969},
  isbn    = {3456789012345},
  volume  = {3},
}
@Book{A:V4,
  crossref= {A},
  title   = {Der Kampf der Häuptlinge},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 04},
  year    = {1969},
  isbn    = {4567890123456},
  volume  = {4},
}
@Book{A:V5,
  crossref= {A},
  title   = {Die goldene Sichel},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 05},
  year    = {1970},
  isbn    = {5678901234567},
  volume  = {5},
}
@Book{A:V6,
  crossref= {A},
  title   = {Tour de France},
  sorttitle   = {Goscinny Rene Uderzo Albert Asterix und Obelix 06},
  year    = {1970},
  isbn    = {6789012345678},
  volume  = {6},
}
@Book{DHS:base,
  editor= {{Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen e.~V.}},
  sortname  = {{Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen}},
  year  = {2017},
  url   = {www.dhs.de},
  urldate   = {2018-04-30},
  maintitle = {Suchtmedizinische Reihe},
  options   = {dataonly},
}
@Book{DHS:nik,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  title = {Tabakabhängigkeit},
  sorttitle = {Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen Suchtmedizinische Reihe 01},
  volume= {1},
  isbn  = {978-3-937587-00-4},
}
@Book{DHS:alk,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  title = {Alkoholabhängigkeit},
  sorttitle = {Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen Suchtmedizinische Reihe 02},
  volume= {2},
  isbn  = {978-3-937587-01-1},
}
@Book{DHS:drogen,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  title = {Drogenabhängigkeit},
  sorttitle = {Deutsche Hauptstelle für Suchtfragen Suchtmedizinische Reihe 04},
  volume= {4},
  isbn  = {978-3-937587-03-5},
}
@Set{DHS:SMR,
  crossref  = {DHS:base},
  entryset  = {DHS:alk,DHS:nik,DHS:drogen},
  options   = {multivolumehead=DHS:base},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

%Cleveland\supercite{fish:drugs:cleveland:use} writes some hard stuff.
Asterix loves fish.\supercite{fish:drugs:evans:intro,fish:drugs:gable:alt,fish:drugs:cleveland:use}

Obelix loves drugs.\supercite{DHS:nik,DHS:alk,DHS:drogen}

Idefix loves Asterix, rotten fish and drugs.\supercite{DHS:nik,DHS:alk,DHS:drogen,A:V1,A:V3,A:V4,A:V5,fish:drugs:evans:intro,fish:drugs:gable:alt,fish:drugs:cleveland:use}

Years ago Idefix loved Asterix, no drugs and good fish.\supercite{DHS:nik,DHS:alk,DHS:drogen,A:V1,A:V3,A:V4,A:V5,fish:drugs:evans:intro,fish:drugs:gable:alt,fish:drugs:cleveland:use} These times have been better\dots

Years ago Idefix loved Asterix, no drugs and good fish.\supercite{A:V1,A:V2,A:V3,A:V5} These times have been better\dots

Years ago Idefix loved Asterix, no drugs and good fish.\supercite{A:V3,A:V4,A:V5} These times have been better\dots

Years ago Idefix loved Asterix, no drugs and good fish.\supercite{A:V3,A:V5} These times have been better\dots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Asterix loves fish. 2a–c//Obelix loves drugs. 1a–c//Idefix loves Asterix, rotten fish and drugs. 1a–c,2a–c,3a,c–e//Years ago Idefix loved Asterix, no drugs and good fish. 1a–c,2a–c,3a,c–e These times have been better...//Years ago Idefix loved Asterix, no drugs and good fish. 3a–c,e These times have been better...//Years ago Idefix loved Asterix, no drugs and good fish. 3c–e These times have been better...//Years ago Idefix loved Asterix, no drugs and good fish. 3c,e These times have been better...]