# Referencing to a standard (eurocode) several times yet different sections

Tags: bibliographies

So I want to reference to several sections in the eurocode without a massive bibliography. Today I'm creating a new @standard for every section in a standary that I need to reference which of course generates i.e 15 references in the bibliography.

Example

> As described in [1] and [2] the choise of parametes in [3]...
>
> BIBLIOGRAPHY
>
> [1] SS-EN 1992-1-1 eurocode section 4.5.6.7
>
> [2] SS-EN 1992-1-1 eurocode section 4.5.6.8
>
> [3] SS-EN 1992-1-1 eurocode section 4.5.6.9

This is what I would like to achieve:

Example

> As described in [1a] and [1b] the chose of parametes in [1c]...
>
> BIBLIOGRAPHY
>
> [1] SS-EN 1992-1-1 eurocode
>
> (a) section 4.5.6.7
>
> (b) section 4.5.6.8
>
> (c) section 4.5.6.9

Is there a nice way?

Comment: Maybe this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463919/118739 may help...

Comment: I guess usually one would just cite the entire thing and would add the specific section/pinpoint in the cite command: `\cite[§4.5.6.7]{en1992}` and `\cite[§4.5.6.9]{en1992}`.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Facing a very similar problem some time ago i modified the `@set` handling of `biblatex` with the highly appreciated assistance of [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) to get the following result:

[image]

Adapting the answer mentioned in my previous comment using the the solution of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463919/118739) and the main part of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470616/118739) to your needs you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,mcite,subentry,sorting=nty,sortsets=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat{entrysetcount}{\mknumalph{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareEntryOption[string]{multivolumehead}{\def\xs@mv@head{#1}}
\define@key{xs@multivolume}{multivolumehead}{\def\xs@mv@head{#1}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{multivolumechild}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnamesequal{author}{savedauthor}}
      or
      test {\ifnameundef{author}}
    }
      {\nopunct}
      {\printnames{author}%
       \newunit\newblock}%
    \iffieldundef{volume}
      {}
      {\printfield{volume}%
       \printfield{part}%
       \newunit\newblock}%
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnamesequal{editor}{savededitor}}
      or
      test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
     }{}
      {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
       \newunit\newblock}%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iflistsequal{location}{savedlocation}}
      or
      test {\iflistundef{location}}
     }{}
      {\printlist{location}}%<- typo
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iflistsequal{publisher}{savedpublisher}}
      or
      test {\iflistundef{publisher}}
    } {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
      {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
       \printlist{publisher}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
    \newunit\newblock%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iffieldsequal{year}{savedyear}}
      or
      test {\iffieldundef{year}}
     }{}
      {\printdate%
       \newunit\newblock}%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iffieldsequal{isbn}{savedisbn}}
      or
      not togl {bbx:isbn}
     }{}
      {\printfield{isbn}}%
    \newunit\newblock%
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  }

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \edef\xs@mv@set{\abx@field@entrykey}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifundef{\xs@mv@head}}
    or
    test {\ifblank{\xs@mv@head}}
    }
    {\entryset{}{}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
     \finentry}
    {\entrydata*{\xs@mv@head}{\usedriver{}{\abx@field@entrytype}\finentrypunct%
       % reload the set so we can access the header via saved
       \entrydata*{\xs@mv@set}{
         % don't issue \leavevmode inside here
         \let\blx@leavevmode\relax
         \setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}%
         \begin{itemize}[label={\printfield{entrysetcount})},labelindent=0.5\labelnumberwidth,labelsep=1ex,itemindent=0pt,leftmargin=*]
         \entryset{\item \ifcsdef{blx@bbx@multivolume\abx@field@savedentrytype}
           {\edef\abx@field@entrytype{multivolume\abx@field@savedentrytype}}
           {\message{^^Jxs Warning: BibliographyDriver blx@bbx@multivolume@\abx@field@entrytype\space undefined
                     ^^J** Using fallback driver multivolumechild
                     ^^J** If you get unexpected entries in the bibliography consider to create a new BibliographyDriver multivolume@\abx@field@savedentrytype.}%
            \def\abx@field@entrytype{multivolumechild}}}{}%
         \finentrypunct\end{itemize}\nopunct}}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
     \finentry}}

\newcounter{cbx@tempcntc}% no. of entrysetcounts we skipped
\newcounter{cbx@tempcntd}% 'predicted' entrysetcount
\renewbibmacro*{cite:init}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastnumber
  \global\undef\cbx@lastprefix
  \global\undef\cbx@lastcount
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcnta}{0}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntb}{-2}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntc}{0}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntd}{-1}}

\newcommand*{\cbx@iflabelnumberequalslast}{%
  \iffieldequals{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}}

\newcommand*{\cbx@iflabelprefixequalslast}{%
  \ifundef\cbx@lastprefix
    {\iffieldundef{labelprefix}
       {\@firstoftwo}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\iffieldequals{labelprefix}{\cbx@lastprefix}
       {\@firstoftwo}
       {\@secondoftwo}}}

\newcommand*{\cbx@iflabelequalslast}{%
  \iffieldequals{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}
    {\cbx@iflabelprefixequalslast
       {\@firstoftwo}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:comp:inset}{%
  \stepcounter{cbx@tempcntd}%
  \cbx@iflabelequalslast
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
     \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntb}}{-1}
       {\multicitedelim}
       {}}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \cbx@iflabelequalslast
      {}
      {\setcounter{cbx@tempcntd}{-1}%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelnumber}%
       \savefield{labelprefix}{\cbx@lastprefix}%
       \savefield{labelnumber}{\cbx@lastnumber}}%
    \ifnumequal{\thefield{entrysetcount}}{\value{cbx@tempcntd}}
      {\savefield{entrykey}{\cbx@lastkey}%
       \savefield{entrysetcount}{\cbx@lastcount}%
       \stepcounter{cbx@tempcntc}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntd}}{0}
         {\multicitedelim}
         {}%
       \printfield{entrysetcount}}}%
    \setcounter{cbx@tempcntd}{\thefield{entrysetcount}}%
    \setcounter{cbx@tempcntb}{-1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:dump}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntc}}{0}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntc}}{1}
       {\bibrangedash}
       {\multicitedelim}%
     \bibhyperref[\cbx@lastkey]{%
       \printtext[entrysetcount]{\cbx@lastcount}}}
    {}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntc}{0}%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcnta}}{0}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcnta}}{1}
       {\bibrangedash}
       {\multicitedelim}%
     \bibhyperref[\cbx@lastkey]{%
       \ifdef\cbx@lastprefix
         {\printtext[labelprefix]{\cbx@lastprefix}}
         {}%
       \printtext[labelnumber]{\cbx@lastnumber}}%
     \global\undef\cbx@lastprefix}
    {}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcnta}{0}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\entrysetpunct}{\finentrypunct}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Reference{ISO:a,
  crossref = {ISO:base},
  title    = {section 4.5.6.7},
  options  = {dataonly},
}
@Reference{ISO:b,
  crossref = {ISO:base},
  title    = {section 4.5.6.8},
  options  = {dataonly},
}
@Reference{ISO:c,
  crossref = {ISO:base},
  title    = {section 4.5.6.9},
  options  = {dataonly},
}
@Reference{ISO:base,
  title    = {SS-EN 1992-1-1 eurocode},
  options  = {dataonly},
}
@Set{ISO,
  entryset = {ISO:a,ISO:b,ISO:c},
  options  = {multivolumehead=ISO:base},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
As described in \cite{ISO:a} and \cite{ISO:b} the chose of parametes in \cite{ISO:c}, all those are part of \cite{ISO}.

Furthermore multiple cites in one \verb+\cite+ command like \verb+\cite{ISO:a,ISO:c,ISO:b}+ are compressed to \cite{ISO:a,ISO:c,ISO:b}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that if you do not use `\cite{ISO}` you have to add `\nocite{}` or it will fail.